# Before past three month's datas in oracle database

Tags: oracle, database-administration

First Step ⇒

```
create table p(px int primary key, d date);
```

Second Step ⇒

```
 insert into p values(1, '23/07/2015');
             ⇒　　　insert into p values(2, '23/06/2015');
             ⇒　　　insert into p values(3, '23/05/2015');
             ⇒　　insert into p values(4, '23/04/2015');
　　　　　　　　　　　　⇒　　insert into p values(5, '23/03/2015');
```

system date is '23/07/2015'.
Question ⇒　I want to delete "(5, '23/03/2015')" before past three month's data. want to know sql query for this function. please help!

Answer (score 1):

```sql
delete from p
where add_months(sysdate, -3) > p.d
```

Comment: ⇒　Yes, now I'm ok! Thanks for your suggestion!